# I'm a new DM and one of my players is abusing Min/Max. I'm looking for advice on how to deal with this fairly

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

The player built a human "dex" barbarian, with Dex and Con the top two attribute scores to maximize the unarmored defense bonus (AC 17 at level 1) and take half damage when raging. He wields a rapier and a hand crossbow, and took the crossbow  expert feat so he can have a bonus crossbow attack, and ignore loading. The first night of gaming, he was making two attacks every turn. I feel that this build is not in the spirit of a barbarian, and I've since figured out the crossbow expert feat wasn't being used properly because of the ammunition limitation rule.

I've asked him to convert the character to a fighter so the character makes more sense and is more balanced, but I'm having second thoughts now. Was this a fair request, or should i just let it play out? I don't want to be overbearing, but I want character creation to make sense and roleplay to remain important.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. As written, it seems pretty opinion-based; there's no way to determine a "best" answer.

Comment: What level are the characters, and how many sessions have you played?  @DanielZastoupil Please write that as an answer, not a comment. (Because you are mostly right).

Comment: If I am correct, the issue here is whether you, as a GM, should be able to tell a player that their character is too powerful or too optimal for your game and whether this character in particular is overly optimized, is that correct?

Comment: He also doesn't get to use Reckless Attack - he's missing out on many of the barbarian's best abilities.

Comment: His build is far from optimal, so I'm confused on the question here. Also, it's asking about fairness, which is completely opinion-based.

Comment: @Miniman This is under the assumption that everyone's using the rules properly.  Assuming they're paying attention to how the Ammunition trait works with a Rapier and Crossbow, how Rage works with ranged attacks, there's a lot of things that first-time players might miss, and could have lead to the belief that it was overpowered.

Comment: Related answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55420/15469

Comment: Also: Character concept is pretty personal as well. You may think of a barbarian as the archetypal "conan" great-axe wielding proud warrior guy. But others may have different concepts. Such as an ex-pirate seeking redemption but prone to violent outbursts. This could still use the barbarian class if the class features fit the PCs ideas. (As long as you remember the way those features works as others have commented)